# How to make Alexa respond two time?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

How do i make alexa to respond as describe using node js ?

```
User: Hello, i am john.
Alexa: Ok, i know who you are you
Alexa: Do you want to know my name?
```

Answer (score 0):

You make it one reponse with a period between the sentences. You can also use Alexa's SSML tags for a longer pause between sentences. Neither requires node.js as it would just be part of the response string, whatever programming language you use.

Here's a getting started tutorial for node.
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/tutorials-code-samples/build-an-engaging-alexa-skill/module-3